# Is there a way to fine-tune my Oracle SQL code?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-tuning

Is there a way to fine-tune my Oracle SQL code below?  All tables are residing in the same schema.

```
MERGE INTO W_PURCH_COST_F TGT USING
(SELECT
  /*+ PARALLEL(8) */
  cost.INTEGRATION_ID,
  cost.X_RECEIVED_ON_DT,
  COALESCE(gaap.ROW_WID,0) X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID
FROM W_Purch_Cost_F_3955 cost
JOIN W_DAY_D wday
ON TRUNC(cost.X_RECEIVED_ON_DT)=TRUNC(wday.CALENDAR_DATE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN WC_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_G gaap
ON gaap.PERIOD               =wday.PER_NAME_ENT_PERIOD
) SRC ON (TGT.INTEGRATION_ID = SRC.INTEGRATION_ID AND TGT.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = 310)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET TGT.X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID = SRC.X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID;
```

TGT is the target table and SRC is the source table, all residing in a staging environment and the same schema.

---

```
Plan hash value: 679420733
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                    |                     |    18G|   256G|       |   186K  (5)| 00:00:15 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  MERGE                             | W_PURCH_COST_F      |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                   |                     |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)             | :TQ10002            |    18G|    10T|       |   186K  (5)| 00:00:15 |  Q1,02 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     VIEW                           |                     |       |       |       |            |          |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER BUFFERED|                     |    18G|    10T|       |   186K  (5)| 00:00:15 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | WC_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_G | 16261 |   269K|       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|*  7 |       HASH JOIN                    |                     |   398M|   228G|   767M|   179K  (1)| 00:00:15 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |        PX RECEIVE                  |                     |    10M|  6014M|       | 18997   (1)| 00:00:02 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |         PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10000            |    10M|  6014M|       | 18997   (1)| 00:00:02 |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|  10 |          PX BLOCK ITERATOR         |                     |    10M|  6014M|       | 18997   (1)| 00:00:02 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|* 11 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | W_PURCH_COST_F      |    10M|  6014M|       | 18997   (1)| 00:00:02 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |        PX RECEIVE                  |                     |   398M|    13G|       | 28134   (2)| 00:00:03 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |         PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10001            |   398M|    13G|       | 28134   (2)| 00:00:03 |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 14 |          HASH JOIN                 |                     |   398M|    13G|       | 28134   (2)| 00:00:03 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | W_DAY_D             | 10790 |   210K|       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |           PX BLOCK ITERATOR        |                     |   383M|  6219M|       | 27963   (2)| 00:00:03 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  17 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL       | W_PURCH_COST_F_3955 |   383M|  6219M|       | 27963   (2)| 00:00:03 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("GAAP"."PERIOD"(+)="WDAY"."PER_NAME_ENT_PERIOD")
   7 - access("TGT"."INTEGRATION_ID"="COST"."INTEGRATION_ID")
  11 - filter("TGT"."DATASOURCE_NUM_ID"=310)
  14 - access(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("COST"."X_RECEIVED_ON_DT"))=TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("WDAY"."CALENDAR_DATE")))
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=AUTO)
   - Degree of Parallelism is 8 because of hint
   - PDML is disabled in current session
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you wanting the query to execute faster?  If so, you need to show us your table specs and index specs.  If you don't have any indexes, start at https://use-the-index-luke.com/. Also, is it the SELECT that is slow, or is it the MERGE?  Does the SELECT part take a long time to run?

Comment: Can you paste the explain plan for the same.

Comment: Also please post an explain plan output

Comment: Do you really need to `trunc w_day_d.calendar_date`? It looks like it might be a dimension table representing calendar dates, in which case I would not expect `calendar_date` to have a time component. Also, you might try doing the whole statement in parallel using `merge /*+ parallel(8) */` rather than just the inner `select`. (You might need to enable parallel DML, or include the `enable_parallel_dml` hint.)

Comment: HI @AndyLester - I want the query to execute faster, the MERGE that is taking long time, Select is runs a couple of seconds, MERGE is taking 24 hours.

Comment: Hi @OldProgrammer , im using oracle sql developer, the free version, i'll see if there's a  explain plan here.

Comment: Hi @WilliamRobertson, You're right W_DAY_D is a dimention table, will it affect the results of the update if i remove it from the join?

Comment: Hi @mohdatif, where can i see the explain plan? I'm using  free Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: @quinsard99 You can’t remove W_DAY_D because you need it for the exchange rate lookup. I was questioning whether you need the `trunc()` function when you join to it.

Comment: HI @WilliamRobertson, So trunc () is from the mapping in our ODI interface, part of the lookup properties, i'm making a history fix  in our data so i included trunc() since its in the lookup of my interface.

Comment: @quinsard99 You can still use text version of explain plan by running explain plan for (query). SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

Comment: Hi @mohdatif ,thanks, learned new today :) . Here is the result. oh characters limit, exceeded. How can i paste?

Comment: @quinsard99 please edit your answer and paste the same.

Comment: @mohdatif, answer pasted.